# REGEX - Allowing multiple spaces and cannot have spaces before or after hyphen(-)

Tags: java, regex, space

For name validation using the Regex, I need to have the below requirements.

- Can include letters, spaces, apostrophe(') and hyphen(-) only
- multiple spaces are allowed between the characters (example: " asd  asd asd asd  ")
- Cannot have spaces before or after hyphen(-) (example: "abc-abc" is allowed, "abc -abc" and "abc- abc" is not allowed)

I'm currently using this Regex:

```
(^[a-zA-Z' ]+(?:[- ][a-zA-Z']+)*$
```

(https://regexr.com/6umck)

This regex meets every requirement except the fact that it's allowing spaces before hyphen.

**How can I disallow spaces before hyphen meeting every other requirement too here?**

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex:

```bash
^ *[a-zA-Z']+(?:(?:-| +)[a-zA-Z']+)* *$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DidLI2/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `*`: Match 0 or more leading spaces
- `[a-zA-Z']+`: Match 1+ of letter or `'`
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `(?:-| +)`: Match a `-` or 1+ spaces
  - `[a-zA-Z']+`: Match 1+ of letter or `'`
- `)*`: End non-capture group. Repeat this group 0 or more times
- `*`: Match 0 or more trailing spaces
- `$`: End

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude a space hyphen or hyphen space from matching.

Note that your pattern can also match just a space as the space is in the character class.

```
^(?!.*(?: -|- ))[a-zA-Z' ]+(?:[- ][a-zA-Z']+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HY3jTy/1)